# TypeScript, Mongoose, Jasmine - requiring schemas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, jasmine

I've been struggling for days with how to build a proper test workflow. I realise that tests should mock database dependencies but the case is that I need to test the whole process, together with real db queries. 
In the following code I need to require my model so that I could perform operations on db such as deleting test data and pushing test data.

The questions are:

1. What is the proper way of referencing the schema/model?
2. Or is there a way of writing Jasmine tests using typescript?

The code does not work, as it says that BucketConfigS.remove is not a function:

```
'use strict';
let BucketConfigS = require('../dist/app/BucketConfig/BucketConfigSchema');

describe('Bucket config collection:', () => {
    describe('GetAll service -', () => {
        describe('Given that there are no configs', function () {
            beforeEach(done => {
                done();
            });
            afterEach(done => {
                BucketConfigS.remove({}, done);
                done();
            });
            it('should return an empty array', function () {
               // test case
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I also tried the following require line:

```
let BucketConfigS = require('../dist/app/BucketConfig/BucketConfigSchema').default;
```

However it brokes the whole test suite (no test results are written out).

The schema file looks like this:

```
"use strict";
var DataAccess_1 = require("./../common/DataAccess");
var mongoose = DataAccess_1.DataAccess.mongooseInstance;
var mongooseConnection = DataAccess_1.DataAccess.mongooseConnection;
var BucketConfigSchema = (function () {
    function BucketConfigSchema() {
    }
    Object.defineProperty(BucketConfigSchema, "schema", {
        get: function () {
            var schema = mongoose.Schema({
                AppName: {
                    type: String,
                    required: true
                },
                Platform: {
                    type: String,
                    required: true
                },
                Segment: {
                    type: String,
                    required: true
                },
                UpdateTime: {
                    type: Date,
                    default: Date.now
                }
            });
            return schema;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    return BucketConfigSchema;
}());
var BucketConfig = mongooseConnection.model("BucketConfig", BucketConfigSchema.schema);
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.default = BucketConfig;
```

This is a compilation result of:

```
import { DataAccess } from "./../common/DataAccess";
import { IBucketConfig } from "./IBucketConfig";

let mongoose = DataAccess.mongooseInstance;
let mongooseConnection = DataAccess.mongooseConnection;

class BucketConfigSchema {

    static get schema() {
        let schema = mongoose.Schema({
            AppName: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            Platform: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            Segment: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            UpdateTime: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
            }
        });

        return schema;
    }
}

let BucketConfig = mongooseConnection.model<IBucketConfig>("BucketConfig", BucketConfigSchema.schema);
export default BucketConfig;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but

```
let BucketConfigS = require('../dist/app/BucketConfig/BucketConfigSchema').default;
```

started working...